# Can't automate typing in Safari with AppleScript when Safari is not the current window

Tags: keyboard, applescript, safari, automator

I've searched all over the web but can't seem to find an answer to this. I developed this applescript to type in safari with the intended purpose for it to keep typing in the background while I worked on other things on my mac. Is this possible in AppleScript? Everything works fine while I'm in the window but the moment I click on another application the script will start typing it where my cursor is. Here's my code:

```
do shell script "open -a \"Safari\" \"" & "https://discordapp.com/channels/640284517051138079/646446075904917504" & "\""

to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)

    tell application "Safari"

        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1

    end tell

end clickClassName

set work to "!work"
set crime to "!crime"
set slut to "!slut"
set deposit to "!dep all"
property workCounter : 0

delay 7
clickClassName("textArea-2Spzkt textArea-2Spzkt scrollbarGhostHairline-1mSOM1 scrollbar-3dvm_9", 0)

repeat
    tell application "System Events"

        repeat with i from 1 to count characters of work
            keystroke (character i of work)
            delay 0.05
        end repeat

        delay 1
        keystroke return
        set workCounter to (workCounter + 1)

        if workCounter mod 5 = 0 then
            delay 2

            repeat with i from 1 to count characters of slut
                keystroke (character i of slut)
                delay 0.05
            end repeat

            delay 1
            keystroke return

            if workCounter mod 50 = 0 then
                delay 2

                repeat with i from 1 to count characters of crime
                    keystroke (character i of crime)
                    delay 0.05
                end repeat

                delay 1
                keystroke return
            end if

        end if
        delay 2

        repeat with i from 1 to count characters of deposit
            keystroke (character i of deposit)
            delay 0.05
        end repeat

        delay 1
        keystroke return
        delay 30

    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: System Event's keystroke can only be sent to the frontmost visible window!

Comment: Scripting an application's user interface only works if the UI is active.